# Peripherals and the new Macbook's USB C system

Tags: usb

My Mac currently has several USB C ports. Would it be possible to connect peripherals to the computer using the [USB C to USB adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter?fnode=8b) which Apple has to offer. And would they work?

Comment: Be aware that many of the lower-cost adapters are also of low-quality construction. You don't mention if this is a desktop or a laptop you are using. If you are using a laptop in a mobile environment with frequent connects/disconnects, the adapter may fail sooner rather than later. High-quality adapters are manufactured by Anker or Belkin (which we use in our school.) In addition, monolithic adapters w/out cables, as are sometimes packaged with USBC-equipped Chromebooks, can be rather sturdy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The USB type‑C plug has pins that directly connect to the USB type‑A receptacle  pins. If you have a device that requires a USB A port, then you can use the adaptor to connect the device to a USB C port on the Mac. Still, I would recommend checking to see if your Mac is listed as compatible at the link you provided.

I should point out there are many cheaper Apple compatible adaptors available, especially if the device requires USB 2.0.

Basically, the adaptor just has wires connecting the plug to the receptacle.

### USB Type-A Connector Pin Assignment

[image]

[image]

> Note: USB type-C plugs are reversible.

```
   Plug Pin Equivalence

Type A Plug      Type C Plug
-----------   ------------
VCC (VBUS)    + V
D-            D-
D+            D+
GND           GND
StdA_SSRX-    RX1- or RX2-
StdA_SSRX+    RX1+ or RX2+
GND_DRAIN     GND
StdA_SSTX-    TX1- or TX2-
StdA_SSTX+    TX2+ or TX2+
```

### References

[USB 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0)
[USB-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#USB_3.0/3.1/3.2)
[USB Type C 3.1 PD to get DC20V output](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439293/usb-type-c-3-1-pd-to-get-dc20v-output)